# R: Bloomberg Session Not Started, Rbbg

Tags: r

i have been running Rbbg for a while without problem. I am trying to reproduce exactly the same setup on another machine (exactly same setup) but Rbbg doesnt work.

Here is the traceback message i get.

> traceback()

7: stop(list(message = "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session Not Started",

```
   call = .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",

       cl, .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o,

           "jarrayRef")) o else cl, "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/St
```

ring",

```
           method), j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString = simplify,



       evalArray = FALSE), jobj = <S4 object of class "jobjRef">))
```

6: .Call(RJavaCheckExceptions, silent)

5: .jcheck(silent = FALSE)

4: .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,

```
   .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, "jarrayRef")) o else cl,



       "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String", method),

   j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString = simplify,

   evalArray = FALSE)
```

3: .jrcall(x, name, ...)

2: conn$blp(securities, fields)

Could you please help on that?